# creating objects while reading xml in java

Tags: java, xml

I was wondering something about xml parsing in java. While I'm reading xml file in java, is it possible to create simultaneously objects of xml tags. Let me give an example.
This is my xml file. I read it. I can get firstname lastname etc... While reading it, i want to create an employee object with firtname and lastname values. I know that I can create an employee class and when I'm reading data I can assign values to this class but I don't want to do it in this way. Does java provide any easier way to create an employee object. I hope it is clear what I mean.

```
<company>
<employee>
    <firstname>Tom</firstname>
    <lastname>Cruise</lastname>
</employee>
<employee>
    <firstname>Paul</firstname>
    <lastname>Enderson</lastname>
</employee>
<employee>
    <firstname>George</firstname>
    <lastname>Bush</lastname>
</employee>
```

Comment: Use JAXB for this.http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html

Comment: So you have employee table already right? Possibly by using reflection, you could create instance and update the properties.

Comment: The link given by Jerry is for JAXB 1 (JSR-31), when people say JAXB today they are talking about JAXB 2 (JSR-222).  Since you are considering using XStream, you may find the following comparison useful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and use [`XStream`](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). It should allow you to create objects in a very simple manner (from their [2-minute tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)), you could do something like so: 
`Employee emp = (Employee)xstream.fromXML(xml);`

However, note that your `Employee` node is nested within the `Company` node, so you might need to do some extra work. As is, your XML would at most be rendered in a class named `Company` which has a list of `Employees`.

Note however, you will need to have the classes which match the XML available before hand.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> I know that I can create an employee class and when I'm reading data I
>   can assign values to this class but I don't want to do it in this way

Why's that ? It seems a simple and intuitive way to do this (e.g. using a SAX parser). However, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel (that's very understandable), then I would check out [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org) or [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html).

Comment: yeah I'm going to check them. Thanks.